# ZF Set Theory exercises on axioms, $\cup \{ \omega \}$, $\cup \cup \{ \omega \}$, $\cup \{ 0,\{7\},\{\{7\}\} \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm new to ZF set theory (second day of study), I'm preparing an exam about it. Here some exercises with my solution, if you could give me some feedback about that!

$1) \cup \{ \omega \} = \{ \{ \omega \} \}$

I know that must be some $b = \cup \{ \omega \}$. But the elements of $b$ are already present here, so I consider the set of union $b \cup \{ \omega \}=\{b, \{ \omega \}\} \rightarrow \{ \{ \omega \} \}$ because it's already inside. Is this legit?

$2) \cup \cup \{ \omega \} =  \{ \{  \{ \{ \omega \} \} \} \} $

Similar to the exercise 1)

$3) \cup \{ 0,\{7\},\{\{7\}\} \} = 0\cup\{7\}\cup\{\{7\}\} = 0\cup\{\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}\cup\{\{\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}\}$

Here I know that $0 = \emptyset$ and $7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ but I don't know how to use this info here. I've done some manipulation, I don't know if this is the end and solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start with a characterization of $\cup b$ where $b$ is a set:$$x\in\cup b\iff x\in y\in b\text{ for some set }y$$

If $a_i$ is a set for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ then $a_1\cup a_2\cup\cdots\cup a_n$ is a notation of $\cup\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$. I use this in 3).

---

1) $x\in\cup\{a\}\iff\exists y[x\in y\wedge y\in\{a\}]\iff \exists y[x\in y\wedge y=a]\iff x\in a$

This for every $x$ hence showing that $\cup\{a\}=a$. This for every $a$ so also for $a=\omega$.

2) In 1) it is found that $\cup\{\omega\}=\omega$ so that $\cup\cup\{\omega\}=\cup\omega$. We will now prove that $\omega=\cup\omega$

If $n\in\omega$ then $n\in n\cup\{n\}\in\omega$ which implies that $n\in\cup\omega$.

If conversely $n\in\cup\omega$ then $n\in m$ for some $m\in\omega$. From this we are allowed to conclude that $n\in\omega$ because $\omega$ is a *transitive* set (are you familiar with that? This actually needs a proof on its own.)

Proved is now that: $$\cup\cup\{\omega\}=\cup\omega=\omega$$

3) $\cup\{0,\{7\},\{\{7\}\}=0\cup\{7\}\cup\{\{7\}\}=\{7,\{7\}\}$

Comment: I was familiar with transitivity because I've studied also other parts after this exercises. Your explanation is very clear! For the 3rd I was almost there, this kind of notation is new for me! Really surprised for $ \cup \omega = \omega$. For confirm, $\{ \omega \}$ are the elements of the natural numbers, and $ \omega $ is THE SET of the natural numbers, right?

Comment: @Alessar: It's not clear to me which thought process led you to describe $\{\omega\}$ as "the elements of the natural numbers", but I can't imagine a way for that description to mean something correct. Rather, $\{\omega\}$ is a set with exactly one element, and that one element is $\omega$.

Comment: Indeed  $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers. Further  $\{\omega \} $ is a set that has exactly  one element which is $\omega$. So it is not correct to say that "$\{\omega \} $ are the elements of the natural numbers".

Comment: @HenningMakholm can you clarify me this passage? $\exists y[x\in y\wedge y\in\{a\}]\iff \exists y[x\in y\wedge y=a]$ In this passage I can't understand quite well why the inclusion became equality (sorry for this trivial question)

Comment: @Alessar $y\in\{a\}$ means that $y$ is an element of the set $\{a\}$. The notation $\{a\}$ reveals that $\{a\}$ is a set that has exactly one element, which is $a$. So then there is only one choice for $y$: it must be $a$.

Comment: @drhab thanks for the clarification; elem. set theory is not so difficult, but the language is difficult for a freshman like me!

Comment: Just want to let you all know that I've passed the exam of foundations of mathematics. Thanks again

Comment: That is nice to hear. Congratulations!!